# properly format postal address with line breaks [google maps]

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Using V3 of the google maps API, is there any reliable way to format addresses with the line break? By this, I mean something like `1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043` should be formatted as

> 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
>   Mountain View, CA 94043

Looking through the response object from geocoding, there is an `address_components` array that has, for the above address, 8 components (not all of the components are used for the address):

```
0: Object
    long_name: "1600"
    short_name: "1600"
    types: Array[1]
        0: "street_number"
        length: 1
1: Object
    long_name: "Amphitheatre Pkwy"
    short_name: "Amphitheatre Pkwy"
    types: Array[1]
        0: "route"
        length: 1
2: Object
    long_name: "Mountain View"
    short_name: "Mountain View"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "locality"
        1: "political"
        length: 2
3: Object
    long_name: "San Jose"
    short_name: "San Jose"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "administrative_area_level_3"
        1: "political"
        length: 2
4: Object
    long_name: "Santa Clara"
    short_name: "Santa Clara"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "administrative_area_level_2"
        1: "political"
        length: 2
5: Object
    long_name: "California"
    short_name: "CA"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "administrative_area_level_1"
        1: "political"
        length: 2
6: Object
    long_name: "United States"
    short_name: "US"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "country"
        1: "political"
        length: 2
7: Object
    long_name: "94043"
    short_name: "94043"
    types: Array[1]
        0: "postal_code"
        length: 1
```

I was thinking that you could just combine parts that you want, like

```
sprintf("%s %s<br />%s, %s %s",
        array[0].short_name,
        array[1].short_name,
        array[2].short_name,
        array[5].short_name,
        array[7].short_name)
```

[edit]I just realized that sprintf isn't defined by default in JavaScript, so just a concatenation would do I guess.[/edit]

But that seems awfully unreliable. Does anyone know the details on the structure of `address_components`, and if it's reliably similar like that for street addresses in the US? If I wanted to, I guess I could look for the proper types (`street_number`,`route`, etc) as well.

I'd love it if anyone had a better way than what I"m doing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or.... (again, assuming US addresses)... there are CASS-Certified services which will do it for you. For example, I work for a company called SmartyStreets and we do address verification. Google, on the other hand, does address *approximation* and not all the results you get will be accurate; it makes best guesses. CASS-Certified software is going to be reliable and accurate.

The [LiveAddress API](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) returns results from a simple REST request. Here's a snippet of the JSON result of the address you used above:

```
 "delivery_line_1":"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
 "last_line":"Mountain View CA 94043-1351"
```

So here it's automatically been standardized and *correctly* delimited by line breaks for you. I think you will find it to be of some use (plus, it's free). Let me know if you have any questions; I'll assist you.

Comment: This was quite a long time ago, but thanks for the response - it's nice to have learned about CASS-certification.

Answer (score 1):

The address components and their types are documented at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types.

What you want to do is loop through the elements and check the values in the types array.  You don't want to always assume that the city is the Nth element etc.  For whatever value of N you choose, it will be wrong more often that you likely want.  You definitely want to check the type.

For street addresses in the US, you'll want to skip administrative_area_level_2 since that's a county which is not usually part of the street address.

Generally, you'll want to put a line break before the element with type locality.  That might be the only line-break rule you need to get a result that is good-enough.

Definitely test with at least two types of potentially problematic addresses:

1) Rural addresses in unincorporated areas.  Maybe pick a random location in the middle of Alaska.

2) Super-dense places.  Brooklyn is possibly a good place for that.  I believe Brooklyn will be listed as the sublocality while New York (City) will likely be listed as the locality.  Check what the legitimate mailing address is.  You might find that you need to use the sublocality if it is present and ignore the locality.  I'm not sure.

In the above, I'm assuming US addresses. All bets are off if you are trying to parse addresses outside of the US.